# Access arbitrary ports on a mobile unit

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, mobile-broadband

I have a mobile unit connected to the internet via 4G. I would like to host some type of listener on this unit, likely a HTTP server, and send requests to it. I would also like for this server to be largely invisible from the outside, hence the arbitrary port. Hosting a HTTP server on a random port is basic enough, but making sure the network communication reaches its destination seems difficult.

Mobile unit has a router, which is assigned an IP when connected to 4G. I would like to `curl` this IP, at some port, and have the request be forwarded to the mobile unit. I have set up port forwarding to make this happen, and it does work when the router is connected to the local wifi. I `curl` the local IP at the port, and the response is forwarded to me. However, on mobile network, I `curl` the IP that the router reports it gets, and I get no response. Is this possible? If so, what is required?

Comment: Most mobile network operators use carrier-grade NAT. What are the first two octets of your router’s public IP address as reported by the router itself?

Comment: First two numbers are 101.119. The mobile unit reports a public facing IP (from `curl ifconfig.me`) as 93.234.